# How to Implement Protected Routes in Next.js 14 with Custom Session-Cookie Backend Without Flicker on Authentication Check

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

I am working on a project using Fastify for the backend and Next.js 14 for the frontend. My authentication flow is session-based, utilizing cookies for managing sessions. Alongside, my backend is responsible for handling user registration, login, and logout functionalities. I have an endpoint that checks if a user is authenticated; it returns a 401 status code if not authenticated and a 200 status code if the user is authenticated.

Cookie has following parameters: secure: true, httpOnly: true, sameSite: strict.
Backend and Frontend are going to be hosted on same domain.

I'm facing a challenge with implementing protected routes on the Next.js frontend. My goal is to check if the user is authenticated before rendering protected pages, redirecting unauthenticated users to a login page. However, I'm experiencing a flicker effect on the client side during the authentication check.

**My Question:**

How can I implement protected routes in Next.js 14 with a Fastify backend, in a way that eliminates the flicker effect during the authentication check? Given that my backend already handles user registration, login, and logout processes, are there best practices or patterns for handling session-based authentication with Next.js and a custom authentication API that avoid this issue?

I appreciate any advice or insights from those who have tackled similar challenges.

Comment: Have you tried Middleware?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset If i understand nextjs middleware correctly, it runs on server side. And my cookie is stored on the client side with httpOnly=true => that means I can't access it's value. But... theoreticaly, when both front and back are hosted on same domain, cookie will also be sent to next server. So, theoreticaly I can make nextjs server validate sessions using secret from backend and redis session store. Will this work? Are there any solutions?

Comment: In your question `httpOnly: true` the httpOnly cookie is a server cookie